# iOS customisable Pie charts issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, charts, pie-chart

i am looking to make a pie chart. but there are so many ways to make it(calayer,bezierpath, thirdParty tool ) which make me confuse. i haven't have enough days to look into each implementations.Can anyone with a experience in making charts guide me on making such Piechart.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your image shows more than just drawing a pie chart.

Comment: so what should i use to get such effects?

Comment: Avoid pie charts unless you know what you are doing. [Save the pies for dessert](https://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/visual_business_intelligence/save_the_pies_for_dessert.pdf) and learn some better ways to visualise data.

Comment: so there is no way to draw such thing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just ended with third party tool. thanks everybody.